# How to transform a user input in rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating an app where users could enter their name that will be returned as chemical symbols (when matching).

So I managed to do in the console like:

```
symbols = {
 "ac" => "Ac",
 "al" => "Al",
 "am" => "Al",
 "br" => "Br",
 "ba" => "Ba",
 "cr" => "Cr"
}

puts "Get your chemical name!"
name = gets.chomp
name.gsub!(/#{symbols.keys.join('|')}/, symbols)
puts name
```

Now I'd like to make it works in the app but I don't know how to create the method ? 
I want it to be displayed only in the views/show

```
= @convertor.name

= link_to 'Edit', edit_convertor_path(@convertor)
= link_to 'Back', convertors_path
```

shall I create the method in my model or else where?

```
class Convertor < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_chemical_name(name)
    symbols = {
     "ac" => "Ac",
     "al" => "Al",
     "am" => "Al",
     "br" => "Br",
     "ba" => "Ba",
     "cr" => "Cr"
   }
    name.gsub!(/#{symbols.keys.join('|')}/, symbols)
    puts  name
  end
end
```

so in my view showI tried something like `=@convertor.get_chemical(name)` but unsuccessful.. 
I need your help please

Comment: You blindly copied your `symbols` hash from a previous answer but neglected to fix the `"am" => "Al"` typo from that answer. You'd also be better off with `Regexp.union(symbols.keys)`, string interpolation for building your regex is fine with those keys but bad habits are bad habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the method can stay in the model.

Short one:

```
@convertor.get_chemical(@convertor.name)
```

would work but this is not a right way to do that.

Correct way would be to change the method in `Convertor` class to not accept any arguments, since it is an instance method and it already has access to `name` attribute. So, after changing the method signature

```
  def get_chemical_name
    symbols = {
      "ac" => "Ac",
      "al" => "Al",
      "am" => "Al",
      "br" => "Br",
      "ba" => "Ba",
      "cr" => "Cr"
   }
    name.gsub!(/#{symbols.keys.join('|')}/, symbols)
  end
```

you will be able to use

```
=@convertor.get_chemical_name
```

Also, I removed useless `puts name` from the method definition -  in Ruby the last evaluated line is already a return value of the method (unless `return`ed before the end of the method).

Also, if by any chance you are using the `symbols` hash anywhere else, you can move it to constant.

Comment: ahhhh cool  I wasn't that far ! thanks for your help ! very appreciated :)
I may come with other questions later ( I will attach the images on the "symbols")